# VBA Excel File System Object

Tags: excel, scripting, runtime, vba

I'm trying to develop a bit of VBA that will check the date modified section on the file. I have found a bit of code online that uses the FileSystemObject to do this, but I run into a "Type Mismatch" error in VBA and was hoping someone could help..

```
Sub test()
Dim FileLastModified As Variant
MsgBox FileLastModified("S:\FILEPATHISHERE.xls")
End Sub
```

(naturally i have entered the actual filepath there!)

```
Function FileLastModified(strFullFileName As String)
Dim fs As Object, f As Object, s As String

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fs.GetFile(strFullFileName)

s = UCase(strFullFileName) & vbCrLf
s = s & "Last Modified: " & f.DateLastModified
FileLastModified = s

Set fs = Nothing: Set f = Nothing
End Function
```

I have just added the Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference, but this is still not working. Any ideas? Am I missing other required references?

Thanks in advance
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declare a variable `FileLastModified` in your test procedure, that has the same name as the function you want to call. If you delete that line it should work:

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox FileLastModified("S:\FILEPATHISHERE.xls")
End Sub
```